# How to save files to Azure File Share from Bot Framework Composer

Tags: azure, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I created bot using Bot Framework SDK that saves the files uploaded by user to Azure File Share.

Then I created another bot using Framework Composer. I’m not able to figure out how to migrate the above code to Composer bot so that I can save the file anytime user uploads a file during the conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to add new functionality to Composer is through the use of [custom actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions).

Essentially you write the new functionality in code (or reuse existing code, whatever the case may be) and then call it from the Composer build canvas as you would a built-in action. The linked documentation shows you how to create and add an example C# custom action to a Composer bot. There is also a [custom action sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/composer-samples/csharp_dotnetcore/projects/CustomAction).